# Strings and Recursion

Tags: c++, string, recursion

So I was looking around online and I found some assignment question someone had posted, and I think I'd like to have a go at it. It deals with a class and something called a derived class which I'm not interested in trying, (mostly because I don't have a clue what that is), but I saw these requirements and was wondering if they can all be done with recursion, using like a void or int function. Here's what I've got:

> A method called strLength that returns the length of the string.
>
> A method called lowerCase that returns the number of lower case characters.
>
> A method called upperCase that returns the number of upper case characters .
>
> A method called vowelCnt that returns the number of vowels in a string.
>
> A method called charSum that returns the sum of all characters within the string.

I think I can do that last one:

```
int charSum(string x, int i)
{
  if(x.size() == i)
    return (0 + x[i]);
  else
    return charSum(x, i + 1) + x[i];
}
```

Although I'm not all that sure about doing it with an actual char, but for the purpose of practicing and seeing how its done using recursion, I'm not too worried about weather it's a char or a string, just that it works.

Check that, I found this, (note, I didn't come up with this one, someone named eazar001 did...):

```
int countString(char sample[], int i, int total)
 {
   if(sample[i] == 0)
   {
       return total;
   }
   else
   {
       return countString(sample, i+1, ++total);
   }
 }
```

Does anybody know how to do the other ones on the list, or have something they can point me to that can show me how to scan a string to look for these things, (especially the upper and lower case stuff, I had no idea there was a difference).
Thanks a million to anyone willing to walk me though this stuff as I try to self teach!

Comment: Your second example is missing a `return` statement in the `else` clause. All your problems should follow pretty much the same pattern, the only difference is what values they accumulate during the recursion.

Comment: This type of question is not a good fit for SO. You're supposed to ask a question that can have specific answer. Asking for general advice leads to ongoing discussions, not answers.

Comment: So should I break them down?

Comment: You should try to write each of them. If you have a problem with one of them, post a question showing what you tried. Well, now that someone has done all the work for you, it looks like you're not going to get a chance, and you're not going to learn as well.

Comment: Oh trust me, I'm learning. This isn't for a class, and I don't just take some answer and use it. I take anything I get and tear it apart backwards and forwards until I feel confident enough to explain it to someone else without having to look anything up, and to be able to do it on a whim. I usually have a hard time following the books I have, and seeing the code makes it soooo much easier to understand and learn for me. That's why I wont take a class until I know I can do it without having to rely on a book to teach me, it's also why I scour the net looking for oddball questions like this.

Comment: Plus, I'll eventually try and figure out how to break this down into a normal function with for loops and whatnot. And I'm going to find out what a derived class is, and how to use these in one, like the original assignment had posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int strlen1(char * s){
    if(*s=='\0') return 0;
    else return strlen1(++s)+1;
}
int lowercase_count(char *s){
    if(*s=='\0') return 0;
    else if(*s>=97 && *s<=97+26) return lowercase_count(++s)+1;
    else return lowercase_count(++s);
}
int uppercase_count(char *s){
    if(*s=='\0') return 0;
    else if(*s>=65 && *s<=65+26) return uppercase_count(++s)+1;
    else return uppercase_count(++s);
}
int isVowel(char c){
    char v[10]={'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'};
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        if(v[i]==c) return 1;
    return 0;
}
int vowel_count(char *s){
    if(*s=='\0') return 0;
    else if(isVowel(*s)) return vowel_count(++s)+1;
    else return vowel_count(++s);
}
```

Comment: OK, since I'm a bit confused how to tell the difference between upper and lower case, could you explain how those two work in telling things apart. I'm going to guess that some sort of number count has something to do with it.

Comment: As for the vowel work, it looks like your first looking for a vowel in one function, and then doing the recursive work in another, calling on your vowel checker function, is that correct?

Comment: Ok. If you want to find the length of a string then you have to go through each charecter and add 1 to the answer (the return statement), until you are at the end of the string, at which point you terminate.

Comment: So, to check if a char is lower case you have to check if it is between a (int value for a is 97) and z (97+26)

Comment: Similarly for upper case you have to check if it is between A (ascii value is 65) and Z (ascii value is 65+26)

Comment: And I feel stupid asking about the string length one after seeing how you did it, check for the null, and count along until you hit it, OI, sometimes I wonder about myself. Thank you so much for this though! This helps me understand two things at once, strings and recursion stuff, both of which were perplexing me a bit.

Comment: Similarly for vowel if your char is a vowel (the isVowel function) then you add 1 to the answer otherwise you add nothing.

Comment: Glad to help :) have fun!

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code those ASCII character codes. C and C++ have built-in functions `isupper()` and `islower()` to tell if a character is an upper- or lower-case letter.

Comment: How do you use those?

Comment: Would that just change to : `int lowercase_count(char *s){
    if(*s=='\0') return 0;
    else if(islower(*s)) return lowercase_count(++s)+1;
    else return lowercase_count(++s);`